# In the Elixir DateTime implementation, what is meant by Calendar.std_offset?

Tags: datetime, calendar, timezone, elixir

In the [docs for DateTime](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/master/DateTime.html#content) I see that Calendar.std_offset is "The time zone standard offset in seconds (not zero in summer times)" from [this link](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/master/Calendar.html#t:std_offset/0)

A Calendar.utc_offset is the offset in seconds from Coordinated UTC time according to Wikipedia.  So what is the purpose of Calendar.std_offset?  What does it do? It seems you could specify an offset purely from "utc_offset".  Is the "std_offset" to account for Daylight savings time only?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The standard offset is the offset to apply to the standard time/UTC offset during summer/daylight savings time for the given zone. So given a UTC offset of 5 hours and a standard offset of 1 hour, the total summer/daylight savings time offset is 6 hours, and the standard time/UTC offset is 5 hours.